# Use a Facade outside Laravel 5 (in CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to get a Laravel package (maatwebsite/excel) to work on CodeIgniter.
The error I get is: `Message: A facade root has not been set.`

Is there a way to get Laravel facades to work under CodeIgniter?

I read this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/ which suggests to me that I need to call

```
Illuminate\Support\Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);
```

But what should `$app` be?

My code so far is this:

```php
// Report.php
class Rapportage extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // This doesn't work, what should I put here?
        Illumiante\Support\Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);
    }

    public function generate_rapport()
    {
        // This is where the error occurs
        return Excel::download(new PersonExport, 'rapport.xlsx');
    }
}
```

```php
// Reports/Persons.php
namespace Exports;

use Person;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class PersonExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Person::all();
    }
}
```

Comment: That package is largely a wrapper around https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet, isn't it?

Comment: That seems to be true. It wraps PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet and makes it very easy to integrate with Laravel Collections (which I already use inside CodeIgniter). Hm.. maybe I could use PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet instead.